# Kubernetes pods unable to resolve host :

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, coredns

I have setup an Azure Kubernetes Cluster using kubenet plugin. All pods and services are running. Also, when I do a `kubectl get pods -n kube-system`  all pods are running.

The issue I have is, the pods are unable to connect to other pods via hostnames. However, if I use the pod ip addresses : portname, they are able to connect.

When I am logged into a pod and do a curl ex:
`pod-x$ curl http://my-pod-y:2000/analysis`

I get the error:

> could not resolve host http://my-pod-y

But when I delete all the coredns pods with kube-system namespaces, and retry the curl commands within the pod, they are able to access the other pods using hostnames!

But when I try after 10 mins it gives the could not resolve host error.

Any pointers on this will be much appreciated.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should probably use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question. Also see [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center.

Comment: the above question is centered around devops where it is a mix of manifest code and the software tool (kubernetes) itself. Is stackoverflow not suited for any devops questions?  Similar questions have already been asked and answered in Stackoverflow, I dont seem to find the answer for the scenario that I am facing.

Comment: Why is this question down voted?

Comment: try updating\reinstalling aks? this seems like an issues with coredns. it might be specific to that particular version

Comment: are you connecting to the pod by its name or by service name?

Comment: thanks for the responses. 
I deleted and recreated the aks cluster, but still unable to resolve hostnames within pod.
Also, tried using service name, with same result.
Within the pod, I then did a ping and the first line of ping correctly showed the ip address, but it hung without any response.
I suspect there is something within our network that is blocking, but dont know how to verify this.

Comment: I am using servicename:port to connect. The strange thing is, most of the time it fails to connect, and suddenly once in a while without any change it connects, but after few minutes it reverts back to 'unable to resolve hostname' error.

Comment: Take a look into logs of coredns, maybe you will see something useful.

Answer (score 0):

Kuberentes uses different DNS schemes for PODs.

The DNS schema for a Pod in the default NS with IP 172.17.0.3 is :

```
172-17-0-3.default.pod.cluster.local
pod-ip-address.namespace.pod.cluster-domain.example
```

If you want to use DNS name, you have to uses services. For a Service test in the default NS the DNS record is:

```
test.default.svc.cluster.local
svc.namespace.svc.cluster-domain.example
```

You can check this here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/